# Generating function counting quaternary sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

I have the following problems:

$1.$ Calculate the number of the n-digits Quaternary sequence containing even $"2"$ and $"1"$ and at least one $"3"$. (When a sequence is made by the digits $1,2,3,4$)

What I did:
I figured that representing $1,2,3,4$ by $u,v,w,x$ gives us that  the generating function for all Quaternary sequences is $$(u+v+w+x)^n$$ therefore the n-digits sequences with even $"1"$ is $$\frac{1}{2} \left((u+v+w+x)^n + (-u+v+w+x)^n\right)$$ and with even $"1"$ and $"2"$ is $$\frac{1}{4} \left((u+v+w+x)^n + (-u+v+w+x)^n\right)
+ \frac{1}{4} \left((u-v+w+x)^n + (-u-v+w+x)^n\right)$$ now I only want to count them so I can put $u=v=w=x=1$ and get a result, but I have no idea how to "spice it" so it will also include at least one $"3"$.
If someone can shed some light it will be much appreciated.

$2.$ the next problem which I have absolutely no idea how to approach to:

Prove using generating functions that for $n<l$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=n}^{l}\dbinom{2i}{k}=\frac{2^{2l+2}-2^{2n}}{3}$$

any suggestion?

Comment: Your last equation does not have an $n$ on the left-hand side. Should there be an $n$ on top of the inner sum symbol?

Comment: hmmm nope, that's exactly how the question is written.

Comment: you are right. there's a mistake with the question!

Comment: Fixed it. sorry for the misunderstanding- my teacher's mistake :)

Comment: For 1., it seems more natural to use an exponential generating function rather than an ordinary power series generating function, since the order of the numbers in the sequence matters.  I.e., 1234 and 4321 are distinct sequences, even though they have the same number of 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s.

Comment: You are asking two distinct questions. Please make it into two separate questions. What would you do if you wanted to accept two answers from distinct users ?

Answer (score 0):

You want *sequences*, so you have to use exponential generating functions (the positions label your digits). Assuming there are "infinite" of each digit available to simplify, you have:

- **Even number of 1 (or 2):**
   $1 + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + \dotsb
          = \frac{\mathrm{e}^z - \mathrm{e}^{-z}}{2}$
- **At least one 3:**
   $\frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dotsb
          = \mathrm{e}^z - 1$
- **Any number of 4:**
   $1 + \frac{z}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dotsb
          = \mathrm{e}^z$

Multiply all, extract $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$:

$\begin{align}
n! [z^n] \frac{\mathrm{e}^z - \mathrm{e}^{-z}}{2}
           \cdot \frac{\mathrm{e}^z - \mathrm{e}^{-z}}{2}
           \cdot (\mathrm{e}^z - 1)
           \cdot \mathrm{e^z}
  &= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{4}
       \left(
         \mathrm{e}^{4 z}
           - \mathrm{e}^{3 z}
           - 2 \mathrm{e}^{2 z}
           + 2 \mathrm{e}^{z}
           + 1
           - \mathrm{e}^{-z}
       \right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{4}
       \left(
          4^n - 3^n - 2 \cdot 2^n + 2 + [n = 0] - (-1)^n
       \right)
\end{align}$

Here $[P]$ is [Iverson's bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), $1$ is the proposition $P$ is true, $0$ otherwise.